# TCP handshake involving more than two ports

Tags: tcp, istio, handshake

I have an application deployed on a Kubernetes cluster. I am using Istio/Envoy in this deployment to control inbound/outbound traffics. I have collected some TCP packets using TCPdump for investigating some issue.

To my understanding, a TCP handshake should only involves a pair of 5-tuple (src-IP, src-Port, dst-IP, dst-Port, protocol).
For example

```
IP: 198.168.1.100 Port: 52312 ----SYN----> IP: 198.168.1.101 Port: 80
IP: 198.168.1.100 Port: 52312 <--SYN ACK-- IP: 198.168.1.101 Port: 80
IP: 198.168.1.100 Port: 52312 ----ACK----> IP: 198.168.1.101 Port: 80
```

But in the packets I collected, what I don't understand is this:

```
10.X.X.X    127.0.0.1   TCP 76  33500 → 15001 [SYN] Seq=3333992218
X.X.X.X     10.X.X.X    TCP 76  80 → 33500 [SYN, ACK] Seq=2228273021 Ack=3333992219
10.X.X.X    127.0.0.1   TCP 68  33500 → 15001 [ACK] Seq=3333992219 Ack=2228273022
```

Notice the SYN ACK was returned from a port 80. First, I thought there could be missing packets and there was actually two handshakes, but looking at the sequence number and acknowledgment number, it seems to be single handshake.

If this is a single handshake, how would you explain this? Is there a technique that does the TCP handshake differently?

Comment: As mentioned [here](https://istio.io/latest/docs/ops/diagnostic-tools/proxy-cmd/#deep-dive-into-envoy-configuration) Istio generates a listener on 0.0.0.0:15001 that receives all outbound traffic to the pod, then hands the request over to a virtual listener. There is [tutorial](https://medium.com/faun/understanding-how-envoy-sidecar-intercept-and-route-traffic-in-istio-service-mesh-20fea2a78833) about how this actually works on medium. Additionally take a look at `2.4 Root Cause` and `Istio Sidecar Interception` [here](http://arthurchiao.art/blog/tcp-handshake-in-modern-network-infra/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If this is a single handshake, how would you explain this? Is there a technique that does the TCP handshake differently?

According to this [blog](http://arthurchiao.art/blog/tcp-handshake-in-modern-network-infra/):

This is a single handshake, just there are 2 separate connections, first goes to envoy [sidecar](https://istio.io/latest/docs/ops/deployment/architecture/#envoy), then envoy sidecar as a middleman send it to your pod.

> So this is the magic: the connection is not established between client and server directly, but split into 2 separate connections:
>
> connection between client and sidecar
>
> connection between sidecar and server
>
> Those two connections are independently handshaked, thus even if the latter failed, the former could still be succesful.

[image]

> Actual view of the two sides: a middleman sits between client and server

---

If you're looking for more informations about the 15001 port itself you can visit istio [documentation](https://istio.io/latest/docs/ops/diagnostic-tools/proxy-cmd/#deep-dive-into-envoy-configuration).

It is explained in more details [here](https://medium.com/faun/understanding-how-envoy-sidecar-intercept-and-route-traffic-in-istio-service-mesh-20fea2a78833).